# how to check if a given list of numbers are odd or even?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to check the numbers in a list are even or odd in order and if not tell me which one.
for example :
1,2,3,4,5 IS OK
but:
1,2,8,3,4,5    number 8 IS NOT OK

I tried to make the list into 2 different lists and then check if the are all odd or all even but I can't
figure out how to check both of them.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
m = lst[::2]
w = lst[1::2]

for i, j in(m,w):
    if i  % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
```

Comment: could you elaborate with other examples? what types of lists are you referring to? only 1 to n? or they could be like `[9, 12, 13, 18, 21, 45, 99, 102]` which has alternate even and odd values in order? Please elaborate your problem with multiple cases AND expected output for others to understand.

Comment: Use `'OK' if all(x%2 for x in lst) else 'NOK'`? What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: no it doesn't have to start with 1 to n.

Comment: i want the list to be [even, odd, even,odd, even] for example

Comment: try with `list(map(lambda el: 'odd' if el%2 else 'even', lst))`

Comment: It sounds like you want to *rearrange* the ordering of the list?  If so, what if the numbers are not enough to do that ordering - eg. ```[even, odd, even, even]```?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
list(map(lambda el: 'odd' if el%2 else 'even', lst))
```